# Open stack screen from Tab screen in react native navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I have a set of screens set up in Stack.Navigation in the following manner

```
<Stack.Navigation>
 <Stack.Screen name = 'Home' />
 <Stack.Screen name = 'Tabs' />
 <Stack.Screen name = 'Settings' />
</Stack.Navigation>
```

I also have a tabs system set up in the `Tabs` screen in the following manner.

```
<Tab.Navigation>
 <Tab.Screen name = 'Tab1' />
 <Tab.Screen name = 'Tab2' />
 <Tab.Screen name = 'Settings' />
</Tab.Navigation>
```

Now I need the tab screen `Settings` to open up the Stack screen `Settings`.
How do I go about doing this with React Native Navigation?

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Edit:

My Tabs screen contains more than just the Tabs, example:

```
<View>
 <View>
  Lots of other content here 
 </View>
 <Tab.Navigation>
  <Tab.Screen name = 'Tab1' />
  <Tab.Screen name = 'Tab2' />
  <Tab.Screen name = 'Settings' />
 </Tab.Navigation>
</View>
```

So the tab content will only cover part of the screen. When I move to the Settings screen I need it to take up the whole screen as it would do automatically when invoked from Stack.Nav.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a listener to the tab screen, prevent the default action & navigate to the `settings` stack screen on tab press.

```js
...

<Tab.Navigation>
 <Tab.Screen 
   name = 'Settings' 
   listeners={() => ({
      tabPress: (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          navigation.navigate('Settings');
      }
   })} />
</Tab.Navigation>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you are wanting to open the stack Setting Screen from the tab navigator.

Would pointing them to the same component, achieve what you are aiming for?

example:

```
<Stack.Navigation>
 <Stack.Screen name = 'Home' />
 <Stack.Screen name = 'Tabs' />
 <Stack.Screen name = 'Settings' component={SettingsScreen}/>
</Stack.Navigation>
```

Followed by:

```
<Tab.Navigation>
 <Tab.Screen name = 'Tab1' />
 <Tab.Screen name = 'Tab2' />
 <Tab.Screen name = 'Settings' component={SettingsScreen} />
</Tab.Navigation>
```

If not, please share more details about the expected behavior.

Comment: Hi @g90! Thank you for responding. So I've tried what you've suggested. When I render the Settings screen from Stack.Navigation it renders a full screen. Problem is when I render Settings screen from Tab nav it comes with the bottom tab navigator. I need it to look exactly the same as when it is invoked from the Stack

Comment: I've updated my post to elaborate further on what the Tabs screen contains